# WordPress Plugin( wp social review engine ) no working with custom theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I'm wondering why approximately 35% of the plugins I use have issues. I created my own custom theme and when I switch over to twentyeleven standard theme, the plugins work.

Is there something specific that wordpress requires to have in the code in order for a plugin to function properly? I know that may be vague but I followed a tutorial that spells out how to do a custom theme. They didn't say anything else needed to be done.

Plugin currently having issues.... Has anyone worked with this wp social review engine?: http://wpsocial.com/product/social-review-engine/

When I want to add the review it is not showing the submit your review button

Here is the site I'm working on: http://listoflife.com/cities/aberdeen-stag-parties/

I'm not sure if this is some sort of javascript conflict or the plugin requires more than just "save settings".

Any guidance would be appreciated. I've worked on this for days and most of the Wordpress help forums all end without an answer or resolved solution.

Comment: Start by fixing the javascript errors that are thrown on home page. Be aware that wordpress uses `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, but how do i do that?

Comment: Do what? fix errors? Start at source of each error thrown in console

Comment: Do you know exactly on this plugin why is not working?

Comment: Not exactly, haven't reviewed site much, but when script errors are thrown they block other script from running....that part is quite straight forward